# How to draw image to canvas if you just have the link to the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript, what's the best way to draw an image to a canvas only if you have the link to the image, like this: `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/car.png`?

Note: the link will be on the same domain incase you were wondering.

Comment: grab the link's href, feed it to an img's .src, and drawImage() the img onto the canvas

Comment: But in my case theres 2000 links, is this really the only way?

Comment: @omega put the links in an array and iterate over each one...

Comment: i can't imagine anything else, but folks here are clever, so we'll see... aside, how would 2000 images fit on one canvas?

Comment: I don't know of any way that you can avoid getting the 2000 images (why 2000?  Can you question that assumption, and find a way to get fewer?  e.g. jqueryui's icons stick about 180 images onto one), but once you have them all, assuming they're small, you can cache their toDataURL()s into localStorage.  Heck, if the canvas is static, you can cache the entire canvas into localStorage.  You still get the images, but at least it would only be once.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate an Image(), set the url, and call context.drawImage(params).

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Comment: If I am doing a for loop where each iteration gets a new link, can I reuse the same image object? Like everytime I change the src, will the onload function fire? Or would it be more faster if I created a new image object for each one?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dYupU/

You just need to define a js Image object, and use drawImage()

```
 var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
 var ballon = new Image();
 ballon.src = "http://i.imgur.com/6l6v2.png";
 context.drawImage(ballon, 100, 1)
```

Comment: If I am doing a for loop where each iteration gets a new link, can I reuse the same image object? Like everytime I change the src, will the onload function fire? Or would it be more faster if I created a new image object for each one?

Comment: You can reuse the same image object, I updated the fiddle check it out

Comment: If speed is an issue, you may want to look into having a sprite sheet of all your 2000 images in one image.  You can call drawImage with extra parameters to use it in this way.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Comment: It does not 'need' it, no.  If you hit run you'll see that the fiddle provided works.  If you use onload, you won't be able to use one js Image object for all the files.  I don't have any proof to say that using one object is faster, but it may well be, and omega asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with multiple links, and an alert inside the loop to show you each link's value

```
var can = document.getElementById('pictures');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var img = ['http://placekitten.com/200/300','http://placekitten.com/100/100','http://placekitten.com/125/125','http://placekitten.com/50/50','http://placekitten.com/150/300'];
for(var i = 0; i <= img.length - 1; i ++){
    var cat = new Image();
    cat.src = img[i];
    ctx.drawImage(cat, 50, 50);
    alert('drew ' + cat.src);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/9RNVL/)**

Comment: What about the onload events? Don't you need to draw it only once the image loaded?